# Making Scons realise that my linker script has changed

Tags: c, ld, scons

I am using Scons to build my C project. I have an external linker file specified to `ld` using the `-Xlinker` flag. My problem is that whenever I change my linker script pointed at by `-Xlinker`, Scons does not take the change into account:

```
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `.' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
```

How can I force Scons to listen to changes to my linker script, and recompile the project when that linker script changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
env = Environment()
env['LINKFLAGS']+=' -T linkerscript.lds '
Depends(program, 'linkerscript.lds')
```

[Reference](http://www.scons.org/wiki/ExternalFiles)

Also for explicit dependencies, [check here](http://www.scons.org/doc/0.96.1/HTML/scons-user/x959.html)

Comment: Thanks! I get the first two lines. What is `program` in the third line?

Comment: last line adds a dependency, so if the linker script changes program will be recompiled http://www.scons.org/doc/0.96.1/HTML/scons-user/x959.html